# Need script to not run if user is logged in

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function

**Goal: To hide specific categories from showing in the post meta area**

The below code achieves that (which is in the theme's functions.php file):

```js
function exclude_these_categories($thelist, $separator=' ') {
        //Exclude the following categories
        $exclude = array('Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3', 'Category 4', 'Category 5', 'Category 6');
        $cats = explode($separator, $thelist);
        $newlist = array();
        foreach($cats as $cat) {
            $catname = trim(strip_tags($cat));
            if(!in_array($catname, $exclude))
                $newlist[] = $cat;
        }
        return implode($separator, $newlist);

}
add_filter('the_category','exclude_these_categories', 10, 2);
```

However, it then hides all categories when editing, not just the specific categories mentioned above:
[missing categories screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AQYu.png)

I need a solution so that the above code won't run if someone is logged in; or add to the code so that the categories show up while editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u should run the filter only if it's not on admin page:

```
if(!is_admin())
{
   add_filter('the_category','exclude_these_categories', 10, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [`is_admin()` check](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/) to ensure that you're not in wp-admin.

But if you really want to check just for logged-in user, then you can use [`is_user_logged_in()` check](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/).

Comment: I tried this: https://jsfiddle.net/y8a047kz/

But it didn't work, I think I have the brackets or something in the wrong spot...